# Como verificar se a última AsynkTask acabou

Tags: android, asynctask

Tenho uma aplicação android que comunica com o site através de json que é obtido da seguinte maneira:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String url = params[0];
    String jsonString = params[1];

    Log.d("Parameters", " Url : " + url + " JSON :" + jsonString);

    try {

        if (client == null) {
            client = ((ProjectApplication) this.activity.get().getApplication()).getClient();
        }


        HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();


        CookieStore store = ((DefaultHttpClient) client).getCookieStore();
        context.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, store);

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        StringEntity stringParams = new StringEntity(jsonString);

        post.setEntity(stringParams);
        HttpResponse httpResponse;

        httpResponse = client.execute(post);


        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }


    return json;

}
```

De seguida eu pego na variável `json`, e dependendo da keyword que estiver no json, eu lanço uma activity no `onPostExecute`. O problema começa quando eu faço duas chamadas destas, o programa não espera pelo fim da chamada anterior antes de executar a atual. Como posso resolver isso? Queria guardar algures a `Status` da última chamada para puder ver se esta acabou, se não acabou então a chamada atual é descartada.

**Nota:** Eu não quero descartar o primeiro AsynkTask, quero descartar o segundo.

Comment: Eu sempre uso o `asynctask.onPostExecute()`, isso não funcionou pra você?

Comment: Como a segunda chamada é iniciada? É por um botão?

Comment: Eu já tinha feito essa questão, e esqueci-me, como posso apagar a anterior, @ramaral? (as duas questões são minhas...) a segunda chamada (onPostExecute) é chamada automaticamente quando o doInBackground (que indiretamente é sempre chamada por um botão) acaba.

Comment: Não deve apagar a anterior, ela já tem uma resposta que responde àquela pergunta. Esta é duplicata porque da forma que está, se eu fosse responder, a resposta seria aquela.

Comment: Fiquei sem perceber onde é feita a segunda chamada.

Comment: a segunda chamada é feita inderetamente , tal como a primeira, através de um botão. Imagine que o utilizador carregou numa tab1 (inicia um AsynkTask), esta não carregou o conteúdo e ele já está a navegar para a tab 2( o que inicia um novo AsynkTask, enquanto que ainda temos o Asynktask anterior a correr para obter os dados do tab1). Espero que agora tenha percebido o que tento fazer.

Comment: Como é dito na resposta indicada use o método `getStatus()` para saber se a AsyncTask terminou. Dependendo do que quer pode, por exemplo, fazer o *disable* da tab 2 no `onPreExecute()` e o seu *enable* no `onPostExecute()` ou cancelar a task quando a tab2 é escolhida ou outra coisa qualquer, só você sabe o que pretende.

Comment: Não tinha pegado nisso a tarde, mas amanhã vou tentar arranjar e, se conseguir, coloco aqui a resposta